# Firebase Hosting is caching my dynamic `robots.txt` on the CDN

Tags: firebase, caching, cdn, firebase-hosting, robots.txt

From Firebase docs, we get that it's supposed to set `Cache-Control: private` as default.

[Firebase Hosting- Manage cache behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache)

[image]

I generate my `robots.txt` on the fly, hence it might change from one request to the next. Because of that, I don't want it cached by the CDN. But to my surprise, I'm getting CDN hits for `robots.txt`.

See:

[image]

I do the same with `ads.txt` and `sitemap.xml`. The same is happening with `ads.txt`, but not with `sitemap.xml`.

Maybe it's something related to `.txt` files. Could this be a bug?

Do I have to explicitly set the `Cache-Control: private`?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure that specific file's cache-control header through the `firebase.json` file like this:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      ...,
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "robots.txt",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

More info in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers).