# 404 Robots.txt and Favicon in Angular Universal with Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase

I am facing issue whenever I verify my robots.txt file using online tool or when visiting

```
mydomain.com/robots.txt
```

---

> Background

---

My project is build in Angular with Firebase Hosting. If I run the project on localhost and visit the robots.txt I can see my robots.txt file.

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

Visit `localhost:4200/robots.txt`

Everythings works perfectly

---

> The Problem

---

The issue occurs if I upload the project on Firebase Hosting.

```
npm run build:ssr

firebase deploy
```

Visits `mydomain.com/robots.txt`

Here, whenever I visit my `robots.txt` path I get 404 error. However, my `sitemap.xml` file works perfectly both on **local** and **firebase** hosting, but in case of `robots.txt`, only local host showing the content of `robots.txt` file. Same is the case with `favicon`

---

> What I did

---

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3734

First attempt:
[Firebase Hosting is caching my dynamic `robots.txt` on the CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236987/firebase-hosting-is-caching-my-dynamic-robots-txt-on-the-cdn)

```
   {
  "hosting": [
    {
      ...,
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "robots.txt",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Second attempt: After searching online for the solution I did below changes to my `angular.json` file

```
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets", 
              "MY_APP/src/robots.txt",
              "MY_APP/src/sitemap.xml"
              
            ],
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it under the public directory 
    "public" ?  in firebase.json file ?

Comment: Err `robots.xml`?

Comment: Sorry its robots.txt. I edited my question

Comment: Its under browser folder. The sitemap.xml exists in the same directory and I can access the content but in case of robots.txt I am getting 404. Both files present in same directory

Comment: I have the same problem using nextjs :\